# Pandas - take maximum/minimum of columns within group

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe df with column names par1,par2,..,par7.
I want to select a subset of the total dataframe.
Within the group par1,par2,par3 I want to select the rows for which par4 has the lowest value and par5 has the highest value in that group.
So from the dataframe:

```
Par1,Par2,Par3,Par4,Par5,Par6,Par7
8,7,0,5,1.5,16.66,20.55
8,7,0,10,1.5,21.64,26.32
8,7,0,15,1.5,26.62,32.58
8,7,0,20,1.5,31.62,37.17
8,7,0,5,3,16.66,27.67
8,7,0,10,3,21.64,36.39
8,7,0,15,3,26.62,46.95
8,7,0,20,3,31.62,54.05
```

I want to return:

```
Par1,Par2,Par3,Par4,Par5,Par6,Par7
8,7,0,5,3,16.66,27.67
```

Because here par3 is 5.0 (lower than 10,15,20) and par4 is 3 (higher than 1.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values(['Par1','Par2','Par3', 'Par4', 'Par5'], 
                      ascending=[True, True, True, True, False])
       .drop_duplicates(['Par1','Par2','Par3']))
print (df)
   Par1  Par2  Par3  Par4  Par5   Par6   Par7
4     8     7     0     5   3.0  16.66  27.67
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. I saw another solution:
`df.groupby(['par1', 'par2','par3']).agg({'par4':'max','par5':'min'})`
But that doesn't give me the other columns in par6, par7. 
Any idea how I can get par6,par7 returned too?

Comment: @Jeroen - Yes, it is problem, so it is reason used `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`